# Disable css for java script

Tags: html, css

I have a date and time picker coded in html how can i disable the css rule for this certain item ?

My code is as follows :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>TaskManager</title>




</head>


<style>
select {  

padding:10px 10px;

width:300px;

background:#262626;

border-bottom: 1px double #171717;

border-top: 1px double #171717;

border-left:1px double #333;

border-right:1px double #333;
}


div.box .mesaj{

padding:7px 7px;

width:285px;

background:#262626;

border-bottom: 1px double #171717;

border-top: 1px double #171717;

border-left:1px double #333;

border-right:1px double #333;

overflow:scroll;

height:150px;

}

div.box .buttonu

{

margin:0 0 10px 0;

padding:5px 7px;

background:#CC0000;

border:0px;

position: relative;

top:5px;

left:320px;

width:100px;

border-bottom: 1px double #660000;

border-top: 1px double #660000;

border-left:1px double #FF0033;

border-right:1px double #FF0033;

}

</style>
<script src="datetimepicker_css.js"></script>




<body>

     <form name="myform" action="/addtasknow.html" method="post">
     <div class="box">

     <h1>Add New Task</h1>
     <label>
     <span>Partner</span>
     <select name="f_friend">
     %body%
     </select>
     </label>
     <label>
     <span>Date and Time</span>
     <input type="Text" id="demo1" maxlength="25" size="25"/>

     <img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('demo1','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'12')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
     <label>
     <input type="submit" class="buttonu" value="Add Alarm" />
     </div>

</form>
```

Comment: A more exact description of your problem, and a complete (working) minimal code snippet would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

A simple jquery trick will do it

```
$('#demo1').addClass('newClass');
```

Create a new class with all the attributes you want like

```
margin : opx !important;
```

It will force css to set for the element to 0px margin.